# Plotly Sunburst - TypeError: sunburst() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

i'm trying to get Plotly's sample code working in a jupyter notebook for the 'Rectangular Data With Missing Values' [use case on their site](https://plot.ly/python/sunburst-charts/). Copying the code from their site verbatim into a jupyter notebook, I get the following TypeError, any ideas?

```
TypeError: sunburst() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'
```

Code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
vendors = ["A", "B", "C", "D", None, "E", "F", "G", "H", None]
sectors = ["Tech", "Tech", "Finance", "Finance", "Other",
           "Tech", "Tech", "Finance", "Finance", "Other"]
regions = ["North", "North", "North", "North", "North",
           "South", "South", "South", "South", "South"]
sales = [1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(vendors=vendors, sectors=sectors, regions=regions, sales=sales)
)
print(df)
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['regions', 'sectors', 'vendors'], values='sales')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to upgrade to `plotly` version 4.5.0 for the new `path` keyword argument to `sunburst` and `treemap` :)

Comment: I ran this code `!pip install plotly==4.5.2` from my notebook and then I added `import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['sex', 'day', 'time'], values='total_bill', color='time')
fig.show()` but I still received the same error ---> `sunburst() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'`

Comment: Did you restart your kernel after installing?

Answer (score 0):

Use these commands and it will run

`pip install --upgrade plotly`
or
`!pip install --upgrade plotly`

Answer (score 0):

```
!pip install --upgrade plotly
```

its working fine. it's due to version **incompatibility.**

After doing this you must need to ***Restart kernel*** if you use an internal **Code editor**..
 But if you use online editor like **GOOGLE COLLAB** or anything you just ***Refresh your browser***.

#update

If you still have any problems, try this specific version, not stuck on it. 
`!pip install plotly==4.8.2`

this is code for better understanding...

```
fig = px.sunburst(df1,
                  path =['CourseP','CourseS', 'Gender'],
                  title = "Complete overview of students with their course and year of college")
fig.show(renderer="colab")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue running Jupyter Notebook on my mac within a virtual environment. Even after upgrading plotly version within terminal to 5.9.0:

```
(plotly_env) $ pip3 freeze | grep plotly
plotly==5.9.0
plotly-express==0.4.1
```

`plotly.__version__` was still showing `4.4.1` within notebook. Checking the library of installed packages directory within the environment, the upgraded package was there:

```
(plotly_env) $ ls lib/python3.8/site-packages/ | grep '^plotly'
plotly/
plotly-5.9.0.dist-info/
plotly_express/
plotly_express-0.4.1.dist-info/
```

I finally came across this [post](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4), and used the following *magic* option to upgrade within notebook:

```
%pip install plotly --upgrade
```

I was then able to use the latest library.